# Running Integration Tests with Seed data

Tags: java, junit, continuous-integration, integration, integration-testing

I am writing an Integration test suite where each of the individual tests are dependent on seed data before they run. (Seed data is the default data I initialize before running the system. Eg: Default permissions, default roles, etc). Each of the integration tests should have a tear down method, where it ensures it returns the system the seed data in the same condition as it was given. If there were any updated on the seed data, it should be reverted to the original state. Is there a way in which I can validate the state of the database to check its initial state before each integration tests run? eg: I can do a select count(*) on seed tables, but that won't help with any updates done by a particular test. Another approach would be to load the seed data after each integration tests, but that would increase the time my integration suite takes to run. I need help with some middle ground approach, where I can ensure the state of my database before each test run without dropping and creating the tables again.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using Spring for this.

Take a look at:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html

You can mark test methods or the test class itself with

```
@Rollback
```

This way, nothing is committed after the test method and you don't have to worry about checking the DB state yourself.